# How to read multiple lines from a text and write to another ? C++

Tags: c++, file, char, readfile, writefile

So basically, I have to read from a text file, using C++, multiple lines. Then, I need to count the voals on each line, and the number that is even tells me to write the line in another text file. But I have a problem with the manipulation :

```
void voals_text()
{
    FILE *input_file;
    FILE *output_file;
    char input_line[1024];
    char output_line[1024];
    input_file = fopen("questions.txt", "r");
    output_file = fopen("result.txt", "a+");
    char line[1024];
    int nr_voals=0;
    while(fgets(line, 1024, input_file))
    {
        for(int i=0;i<1024;i++)
        {
            if(line[i]>=33 && line[i]<=126)
            {
                cout<<line[i];
              if(line[i]=='a' || line[i]=='e' || line[i]=='i' || line[i]=='o' || line[i]=='u')
              {
                  nr_voals++;
              }
            }
        }

        if(nr_voals%2==0)
        {
            fputs(line, output_file);
        }
        nr_voals=0;

    }

    fclose(input_file);
    fclose(output_file);
}



int main()
{
    voals_text();
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is with reading. I have to put the entire line in a char. But I do not know the lenght of the line beforehand, so I assume it is max 1024 wide. But if it is less, the bits that are not used are filled with weird chars.
When I iterate to see wether my line contains an even number of voals or not, my counter counts the strange chars too, and I recieve very very weird results.
Can explain me somebody why? And also, how should I read and write the files in a more clever way? (without using ifstream and fstream).
Thank you very much!

Comment: use `std::string` and `std::stream`

Comment: Check the length of the string using `strlen()` and just iterate up to this number. Currently you are reading past the null-terminating character in each string. Or check for the null character and then break if you hit it. Eg `if(line[i] == ‘\0’) break;`. But this is C code really, not C++.

Comment: Do not work with buffers manually. Let C++ standard library classes do it for you automatically. Create std::ifstream object and read data to std::vector<std::string> with std::getline. After that iterate through std::vector<std::string> to process data.

Comment: @maksim_volodin that was my first approach, but my professor wants to use this hard way. It is a bit weird bc I should write this code, on hard way, like without using some predifined libraries. But thank you !

Comment: @DS_London Thank you! I did not think of that! I will try! Thank you very much !!!!!

Comment: @DS_London Yeah! You are right! But it solved my problem, what you have told me. Thank you very much !!!!1